# Jayway JsonPath "match all" (..) equivalent in Gpath

Tags: java, groovy, automation, rest-assured, jsonpath

I would like to fetch all embedded json elements but I could not make it working. Let's say I would like to filter all b's here. What gpath syntax to filter all b's here?

```
{
a:{
c: {
b:1
}
b:45
d: {
b:444
}
}
```

I can use `$..b` in Jayway, but, how shall I use it for Groovy Gpath. 
I'm working with Rest-Assured that uses Groovy Gpath. In general, I would like to write an expression for "match all". In Jayway JsonPath, we can use `..`, Is there any equivalent of this in Groovy Gpath?